# How to print separate loops on the same line?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to sort this array in Ascending and Descending order, please help me out. I have two separate loops and i want to print both on the same line, If i cannot do this, please inform me a another method to do so. This is an assignment, if anyone was wondering.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Lab10c{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Ascend\t\tDescend\n");
            String ss[] = new String[]{"Hi", "Hello", "Greetings", "Howdy", "Welcome"};
            Arrays.sort(ss);
            for ( int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++){
                System.out.print(ss[i] + "\n");
            }
                for (int r = ss.length -1; r>=0; r--){
                    System.out.println(  "\t\t" + ss[r]);   

                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the current printout:

```
    Ascend        Descend

    Greetings
    Hello
    Hi
    Howdy
    Welcome
            Welcome
            Howdy
            Hi
            Hello
            Greetings
```

I need it to print as the two separate columns lining up. Thanks! 
p.s Sorry if I'm unclear, I'm new to the site :)

Answer (score 2):

To do this you must, in any case, get two elements on each iteration.

This means that at iteration `i` you will need to fetch both the element at `i` positions from the start and at `i` positions from the end.

You already have a loop that starts from the end and goes backward so you can easily see that this will do the trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
  int fromBegin = i;
  int fromEnd = ss.length - 1 - i;

  System.out.println(ss[fromBegin]+"\t"+ss[fromEnd]);
}
```

Both `fromBegin` and `fromEnd` will move in a specular way along the array.

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
        for ( int i = 0,j=ss.length-1;; i < ss.length; i++,j--){
            System.out.println(ss[i] + "\t\t"+ss[j]);
        }
```

Comment: Works, but overly complicated for this situation.

Comment: @fd. What complication you found in this logic.In this logic added one extra variable j.

Comment: Separately initializing and decrementing `j` is IMO more complicated to think about than simply calculating `j` from `i` each iteration.

Comment: @fd. Do you think that the ss array will increase the size in between. If i < ss.length; is correct then j-- wont fail.

Answer (score 0):

**Why the elemenets is printed as you mentioned?**

In your code ,  for the first for-loop,

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++){
        System.out.print(ss[i] + "\n");
    }
```

`System.out.print(ss[i] + "\n");` equals to `System.out.println(ss[i])`, when a element in array is printed, a **newLine**() will print as well.

Then the second for-loop executes.

```
        for (int r = ss.length -1; r>=0; r--){
            System.out.println(  "\t\t" + ss[r]);   
        }
```

The element printed in this loop does not print from the first line in sonsole. That'way you got the result:

```
Ascend        Descend

Greetings
Hello
Hi
Howdy
Welcome
        Welcome
        Howdy
        Hi
        Hello
        Greetings
```

**How to fix it?**

You need to combine the 2 for-loop together like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
        //Print element in Ascend order
        System.out.print(ss[i]); 

        //Print element in Descend order in the same line
        System.out.println("\t\t" + ss[ss.length - i - 1]);
    }
```